# Expectation Maximizing Strategy for a Betting Game

Tags: probability, expected-value

Find the expected value for a player of the following game who applies an expectation-maximizing strategy.

The player is given one dollar to start and may not bring additional money into to the game. A standard 52-card deck of cards is shuffled and dealt, and before each card is dealt, the player has the opportunity to bet, at even odds, on whether the card is red or black.

For example, if the player bets 50 cents that the first card off the top of the deck is red, and is correct, the player will have 1.50 available to wager on the next card. If the player subsequently bets 1.50 that the second card is black, and is wrong, the player then has no money, and cannot make bets for the rest of the game.

Find the expected value of the game for a player using an expectation-maximizing strategy. So this problem requires finding both an expectation maximizing strategy, as well as the expected value using that strategy.

Comment: Is the player required to make a bet on each card?  Or can the player wait until the remainder of the deck is monochromatic before placing his first bet?  (I think that's likely to be the optimal strategy but off the top of my head I don't see how to prove it's optimal.)

Comment: Is there any reason to think this has a closed-form solution? One can write out the recurrence via dynamic programming/backwards substitution pretty straightforwardly, but explicitly computing the value seems hard.

Comment: As what commented above: If we have a monochromatic deck, we will always all in for each card, so we will always get $2^nw$ as our final wealth, where $w$ is the initial wealth and $n$ is the size of the deck. Consider a the simplest bichromatic ending 1B1R, and assume we bet proportion $p$ of our wealth $w$ for the second last card. It will always reduce to a one card ending in which we guarantee to get a double. The expected wealth is $w(1+p)\times2\times1/2+(1-p)\times2\times1/2=2w$ which is independent of the choice $p$. I have try a few recurrence and they are all independent of $p$.

Comment: If the guess is correct (have not prove yet), then the optimal strategy is just wait until a monochromatic deck and all in (the amount to bet in previous card does not matter!). Create a table in spread sheet and the final expected value for 26B26R is approximately $9.081330w$.

Comment: Bets of $0 are allowed. Also I believe BGM's calculation is correction, I'm currently working on a proof.